# How can I pass layout arguments to a partial view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Let's say I have a list of products. I want to display a list of products from a certain vendor on the vendor page. I also want to show a complete list of products on the products page. For this I am using a partial view

```
@Html.Partial("_ProductList", Model.Products)
```

The partial view is just a basic table with a bunch of columns.

One of these columns shows the Vendor name. On the products page this is useful, but to show the when the user is already on the vendor's page, showing the vendor name for every single product is not useful.

What I want to know is this: What is the recommended way to pass this sort of layout configuration to the partial view?

Is it to use the ViewData argument?

```
@Html.Partial("_CallList", Model.Calls, new ViewDataDictionary{{"HideCompany", true}})
```

When doing this I find I have to do lots of casting in my partial view, and it really messes up my templates.

```
    @if (!(bool)ViewData["HideCompany"])
    {
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
    }
```

Also, if I want to put my Paginator in the partial view, how can I generate urls without specifying the actionName ?

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page = page }));
```

The action name isn't going to be the same, depending on which view is embedding the partialview, so it becomes another thing I have to pass to the partialview in the ViewData.

```
@Html.Partial("_CallList", Model.Calls, new ViewDataDictionary{{"ActionName", "Details"}, {"HideCompany", true}})
```

It just gets uglier and uglier.

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action((string)ViewData["ActionName"], new { page = page }));
```

In previous frameworks I have used, I didn't have to specify the action name, it just used the action that was currently active.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it to use the ViewData argument?

As you already have seen that would be absolutely horrible.

> What I want to know is this: What is the recommended way to pass this
>   sort of layout configuration to the partial view?

By using a view model of course:

```
public class ProductsViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public bool HideCompany { get; set; }
    public string PageAction { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public ProductsViewModel Products { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
@Html.Partial("_ProductList", Model.Products)
```

and then:

```
@if (Model.HideCompany)
{
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
}
```

and then:

```
@Html.PagedListPager(
    Model.Products, 
    page => Url.Action(Model.ActionName), new { page = page })
)
```

and so on...